# How to use Git ignore file to prevent uploading vendor folder and others configuration files of laravel to the git branch. What is the proper way?

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore

After installing laravel debugger package (barryvdh), some of my file like (composer.lock, app.php) has been updated and I don't want to upload those files to my git branch, So that, I added those file name to the gitignore file. After that, I ran "git status" command, and as normally git bash shows me the updated files. Then, I run (git add -All) command to add the files, after that I ran commit and push command, But all of the files that I've just added to the git ignore file, that also uploaded to my branch.

Comment: Adding them to the .gitignore file is how you do that.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: I add the file name to my .gitignore file but not working. When i make a commit and push the commit to my git branch, then all the configuration files like autoload.php, app.php uploaded to my git branch.
Please tell me how can I remove the changes from my git branch and what is the proper way to use gitignore

Answer (score 4):

Add your files to the Gitignore file and dont forget to remove them from git with

`git rm -r directory_to_ignore` or
`git rm file_to_ignore`.

Regards

Comment: Thank You. It's really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

> [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore

If you are using Laravel 5.3, following are the files and directories that are going to be ignored. Here you will find out how they ignored **vendor** directory by using `/vendor` and configuration files like `.env`

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env
```

Here /vendor will ignore vendor directory with all of its sub-directories.

Comment: After installing laravel debugger package (barryvdh), some of my file like (composer.lock, app.php) has been updated and I don't want to upload those file to my git branch, So, added those file name to the gitignore file. After that, I ran "git status" command, and as normally git bash shows me the updated files. Then, I run (git add -All) command to add the files, after that I made commit and push command, But all of the files that I just added to the git ignore file, that also uploaded to my branch. What can I do, brother?

Comment: Update your question and paste your current .gitignore contents. Let's re-check.

Comment: In your case adding `composer.json` and 
`composer.lock` in your root's `.gitignore` file should work.

Comment: New version of Laravel will generate automatically the gitignore file containing the follow files/folders: `/node_modules`, `/public/hot`, `/public/storage`, `/storage/*.key`, `/vendor`, `.env`, `.env.backup`, `.phpunit.result.cache`, `docker-compose.override.yml`, `Homestead.json`, `Homestead.yaml`, `npm-debug.log`, `yarn-error.log`, `/.idea`, `/.vscode`

Answer (score 0):

add **vendor** to .gitignore in your project

```
vendor
```

not

```
.vendor
.vendor/*
```